# div rollover getting child divs to change color

Tags: css

I have 3 child divs inside a parent div, at present only parts of the child divs change color on mouse over, I want all the child divs to change color on part mouse hover. thanks

I have tried the code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title> 
        <style>
        .container {
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 35px;
        }
        .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: #333;
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        .bar1:hover, .bar2:hover, .bar3:hover {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style=" text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by selecting children of your parent node when hovered.

Your current code:

```
.bar1:hover, .bar2:hover, .bar3:hover {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

... will apply to each element individually (i.e., `.bar3` itself will need to be hovered to trigger that state).

Instead, you want to select child elements of `.container:hover`:

```
.container:hover .bar1, .container:hover .bar2, .container:hover .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

This will apply the styles to:

1. `.bar1`, when `container` is hovered
2. `.bar2`, when `container` is hovered
3. `.bar3`, when `container` is hovered

EDIT: I didn't realize at first that `bar1` is a sibling of the other two. Updated my answer to apply style based on `container:hover`.